# How to refer sub modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following structure.

[image]

Following is the code from call_module1_module2.py. This works fine. I am able to refer to both the modules.

```
from module1.file1 import *
from module2.file2 import *

function1()
function2()
```

However, when I try to call function1 in file1.py of module1 folder from  file2.py in module2, using the code below

```
from tmodules.module1.file1 import *
```

I get an error that module 'tmodules' is not found. It is the name of the parent folder / project.

What am I missing? all the **init**.py are empty. Should I add anything to that file?

Comment: script can't see parent folder. It can see only other scripts/folders in the same folder. Or you would have to add to `PYTHONPATH` folder which is parent for `tmodules`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html -- section 6.4 says that we can refer by the folder name. which is by default the namespace.

Comment: but only modules in the same folder, not parent. Or modules in folders which are in `PYTHONPATH`. Or you can add to `sys.path` folder which is parent for `tmodules`

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that I commonly use:
 1) Refer to the submodule from the root folder, eg:

```
from top_module.child_folder.some_submodule import some_function
```

2) If you are located just one level below you can do:

```
from ..parent_folder.some_submodule import some_function
```

2bis) If you are in the same folder, then:

```
from .hello_brother_module import some_function
```

You can also add the path to `sys.path` but I personally find this solution inelegant

Comment: I already tried the solution 1) which is from tmodules.module1.file1 import *. That's what gave me the error module not found even though it is the top module name.  Even I don't like the sys.path method.